# Why is this enquiry form not displaying error messages?

Tags: php, html, forms, material-design

I have an enquiry form in a page created using Material Design Lite Library, the form is in the last section of the page. The HTML form code is below:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
     <h1 class = "enquiry--header"> Enquiry </h1>
     <form method="post" action = "index.php">
     <div class = "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
       <input type = "text" id="name" name = "name" class = "mdl-textfield__input name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<p class = 'message'>$errName</p>";?>
    <div class = "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input type = "text" id="email" name = "email" class = "mdl-textfield__input email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" name = "email" for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<p class = 'message'>$errEmail</p>";?>
    <div class = "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <textarea type = "text" id="enquiry" name = "enquiry" class = "mdl-textfield__input enquiry"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['enquiry']); ?>" name = "enquiry"></textarea>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Your Enquiry</label>
    </div>
    <?php echo "<p class = 'message'>$errMessage</p>";?>
    </form>
    <div id = "submit" name = "submit" type = "submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-color--grey-900  mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Send
    </div>
    <?php echo $result;?>
</div>
```

The PHP code:

```
$name = null;
$email = null;
$message = null;
$from = null;
$to = null;
$subject = null;
$errName = null;
$errEmail = null;
$errMessage = null;
$errResult = null;
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];
       $from = 'Contact-Us'; 
       $to = 'xyz@gmail.com'; 
       $subject = 'Enquiry';

       $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

       // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
           $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'],   FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
           $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }


    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
           $result='<div class="success">Thank You! We will reply shortly</div>';
           $_POST = array();
        } else {
           $result='<div class="error">Your message could not be sent.</div>';
        }
    }
       }
   ?>
```

The result div is not updating nor are the error messages displaying when the form is submitted as the fields are left blank. I am using MAMP to test it locally.

Comment: `<div id = "submit" name = "submit"...` is wrong for a few reasons.

Comment: You also gave your textarea the same name twice. Keep debugging.

Comment: Could you tell me the reasons and also which one should I change so the PHP function works?

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? If you just had these two elements, you would be drawing a couple warnings. Also are you using javascript to submit the form? You must be since there is no submit button.

Comment: Consult the manual on dealing with forms http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: @Rasclatt  *"You must be since there is no submit button."* - They're relying on that "div" actually ;-)

Comment: PHP error log only shows notices. Will changing the div id submit to a button change things? I am not using any javascript.

Comment: Well, it is good practice to fix the notices...it's sort of sloppy to just leave those. How do you submit the form without a submit button? I assumed since you are using  a `<div>` that looks like a form button you were using js to submit, now for sure that's no good. Try putting that inside the form tags and change it to `<input type="submit" ` instead of `<div`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I assumed much too much on this one... :D

Comment: @Rasclatt, Thank you! You solved the issue.

Comment: @Rasclatt You give them tools but they still wait for a spoon *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was actually thinking there was a clever Javascript that was left out of this snippet that was triggered by a, rather *unconventional*, div that gathered the form data...imagine my disappointment! Lol.

Comment: @Rasclatt *"Clever"* would be the operative word. However; even if it "could" work, it would still require it to reside inside the `<form></form>` tags, IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` Directly under your `<?php` opening tag to make sure your error reporting displays all.

Comment: Did you not see the comments left under the question? Plus, it's already been solved (in there). Your "Try...", is really a comment where Rasclatt already suggested that person to check for errors.

Comment: sending someone back to things they have already tried is kinda pointless. Nowhere in the comments does it specify the code i suggested. Just told to go investigate further. As for @fred-ii, you had no help to him, except for criticism. SO, in my belief, is to help people who are trying to learn to code. Maybe a little help would benefit them. Obviously he isn't a "can i have the code plz" user.

Comment: I think what @Fred-ii- is saying is that I told the OP to see if there are errors and they acknowledged there were, ergo they at least know how to look at errors. A little investigation on their part would discover what you are suggesting. Secondly, the OP did as was suggested in the comments, which was turn the `<div` to `<input` and move it into the form. The user then reported the issue was resolved, so your answer is redundant and does not address the actual issue. Your answer should be, at most, a comment.

Comment: @JamesWalker [*I believe this is close enough*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181649/why-is-this-enquiry-form-not-displaying-error-messages/39182286?noredirect=1#comment65704899_39181649) - where the OP responded with [*this comment*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181649/why-is-this-enquiry-form-not-displaying-error-messages/39182286?noredirect=1#comment65704923_39181649) which does imply that they were getting notices after all. Your *"you had no help to him, except for criticism"* comment, is out of line. I've given them enough to read up on.